# Default authorizations for new users with internal authorization

Tags: permissions, cassandra

If you switch on Cassandra's [*internal authorization*](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/a-quick-tour-of-internal-authentication-and-authorization-security-in-datastax-enterprise-and-apache-cassandra/) feature, by using the `CassandraAuthorizer` as the `authorizer`, and you create a new user (using [`CREATE USER`](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_user_r.html)), what permissions does that user have by default?

- Does the new user have full permission? So if you want the user to have specific permissions you must [`REVOKE`](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/revoke_r.html) permissions.
- Does the new user have no permission? So if you want the user to have specific permissions you must [`GRANT`](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/grant_r.html) permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New users do not have any permissions by default, unless you create them with the `SUPERUSER` keyword.

To [GRANT](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/grant_r.html) your new user permissions, you must do so on a per-keyspace basis:

```
GRANT MODIFY ON KEYSPACE customers TO mynewuser;
GRANT MODIFY ON KEYSPACE products TO mynewuser;
GRANT SELECT ON KEYSPACE customers TO mynewuser;
GRANT SELECT ON KEYSPACE products TO mynewuser;
```

Or, if you want that user to have all permissions on a particular keyspace, you can use the `ALL` permission as well.

```
GRANT ALL ON KEYSPACE orders TO mynewuser;
```